# How can i change the content of a paragraph on a html page from back end

Tags: php, html, back

I want the admin can change the  contents of the html page after successful login.

How can I show the contents of html page in an editable format fetching all the contents from the html  page.

So that admin can modify contents and then save it to change the front end.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to set up an CMS upfront.

Anyway, you can try out this link `http://www.techsling.com/2011/12/10-ways-to-convert-a-simple-htmlcss-website-into-a-content-management-system/`. I personally have some experience with Surreal, but I would not recommend it.

If you really think of content management, you should go with a CMS (one of the big 3: Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal).

Hope that helps

Comment: I don`t want to use cms.
Just its sample to show someone , just tell me the basic coding way.

Not the cms way.
Thanks for your time